# Finding eigenvalues of a particular $3\times3$-matrix, i.e. solving a third order polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, cubics, characteristic-polynomial

Consider the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}2&1&0\\1&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

The characteristic polynomial is of the form
$$(1-\lambda)^2(2-\lambda)-1 = 0.$$
Expanding this out, we get
$$\lambda^3 - 4\lambda^2 +5 \lambda -1 = 0.$$
How would I go about solving for $\lambda$ in this case? Do I have to do long division to find a factor? If that's the case, do I just guess and check factors until I get a nice division with no remainder?

Thanks.

Comment: In this case it is not so hard to check that $e_3 = (0,0,1)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue 1. Hence you indeed can do a long division with $\lambda -1$.

Comment: There is an error in the determinant, characteristic polynomial,  last term is $(1-\lambda)$, not 1

Answer (score 3):

The characteristic polynomial is not $(1-\lambda)^2(2-\lambda)-1$, it is
$$(1-\lambda)^2(2-\lambda)-(1-\lambda),$$
from which it is immediate that $\lambda=1$ is an eigenvalue.

In general, when you are asked to compute eigenvalues of a matrix as an exercise, the divisors of the constant coefficient are good candidates. In this case these are just $1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial is $$(1-\lambda)^2(2-\lambda)-(1-\lambda)=0$$
$$\implies (1-\lambda)\bigg((1-\lambda)(2-\lambda)-1\bigg)=0$$
$\implies \lambda=1$ or $\lambda^2-3\lambda+1=0$
$\implies \color{red}{\lambda=1}$ or $\color{blue}{\lambda=\cfrac{3+\sqrt5}{2}}$ or $\color{#180}{\lambda=\cfrac{3-\sqrt5}{2}}$